# Копирование всех данных до конца листа

Tags: excel, vba

Макрос копирует данные с одной книги в другую. Нужны данные с A5 по R5 и все заполненные строки "ниже" этих ячеек. Макрос работал когда книга "приемник" была той из которой запускался макрос. Пытаюсь сделать запуск из третей книги, ошибка method range of object _worksheet failed в строке 
shtsrc.Range("A5", Range("R5").End(xlDown)).Copy. Что не верно?

```html
Sub updateV_ostatki()
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With
    
    Dim wbksrc As Workbook
    Dim wbkdst As Workbook
    Dim shtsrc As Worksheet
    Dim shtdst As Worksheet

    Set wbksrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\ppweb2.xls")
    Set wbkdst = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Остатки м3_v4.xlsm")
    Set shtsrc = wbksrc.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtdst = wbkdst.Sheets("Данные")

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Откорректировать диапазон-источник '
    shtsrc.Range("A5", Range("R5").End(xlDown)).Copy
    ' Откорректировать диапазон-приёмник '
    shtdst.Paste Destination:=shtdst.Range("B:B").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    
    wbksrc.Close savechanges:=False
    wbkdst.Save
    wbkdst.Close
    
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Range без указания конкретного листа - берётся с активного листа активной книги. `shtsrc.Range(shtsrc.Range("A5"), shtsrc.Range("R5").End(xlDown)).Copy`. Ещё лучше - переключиться в нужную книгу на нужный лист, т.е. предварительно `wbksrc.Activate : shtsrc.Activate `.

Comment: Активация листа - не лучшее решение (медленно). Правильнее - первый совет (с указанием родителя).